# Creating random ratios that add up to 1 by group

Tags: r, random, sample

I have a dataset as follows:

```
panelID= c(1:50)
year= c(2005, 2010)
country = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
urban = c("A", "B", "C")
indust = c("D", "E", "F")
sizes = c(1,2,3,4,5)
n <- 2
library(AER)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(   country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    year = c(replicate(length(panelID), sample(year, n))),
                    sales= round(rnorm(10,10,10),2),
                    industry = rep(sample(indust, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    urbanisation = rep(sample(urban, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    size = rep(sample(sizes, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n))
DT <- DT %>%
group_by(country) %>%
mutate(base_rate = as.integer(runif(1, 12.5, 37.5))) %>%
group_by(country, year) %>%
mutate(taxrate = base_rate + as.integer(runif(1,-2.5,+2.5)))
DT <- DT %>%
group_by(country, year) %>%
mutate(vote = sample(c(0,1),1), 
votewon = ifelse(vote==1, sample(c(0,1),1),0))
```

I would like to add a variable to this dataset called `ratio`. I want `ratio` to be a random number between 0 and 1, and I want the sum of these ratios by country to be 1.

How would I go about creating such a column? The only thing I could think of is manually creating vectors which add up to one and then sampling from those vectors.

EDIT: The countries do not have equal entries:

```
> table(DT$country)

 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J 
 6 10 14  6 14 10 10  8 10 12 

ratio_sample_6 <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.05, 0.15, 0.2)
DT[,ratio:=sample(ratio_sample_6, replace = FALSE), by="country"]
```

But even that I could not get to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `ratio_sample_6 <- sample(1000, 6); ratio_sample_6 <- ratio_sample_6  /sum(ratio_sample_6)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer Allan. Sorry, I should have added that. Not every country consists of the same amount of entries. See EDIT.

Comment: Or pick random numbers and normalize by country: `DT[, ratio := runif(.N)][, ratio := ratio / (sum(ratio)), by = "country"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick random numbers and normalize by country:

```
## data.table version
DT[, ratio := runif(.N)][, ratio := ratio / sum(ratio), by = "country"]

## dplyr version
DT %>% group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(
    ratio = runif(n()),
    ratio = ratio / sum(ratio)
)
```